# Reading large number of records in REST service

Tags: apex, rest-service, largedatavolumes, read-only

This is a apex class for a  REST service fro inserting multiple records into a custom salesforce object- I am getting a **System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001**  error because my org data is huge. I did some research and found that @ReadOnly cannot be used for REST services. Is there any other way i can read data from the salesforce db?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MultiTicket/*')
global with sharing class MultiTicketRestController{
   global class RequestBody {
       global List<Ticket__c> tickets;
   }

    @HttpPost      
    global static List<Ticket__c> createBulk(MultiTicketRestController.RequestBody req) {

     List<Activity__c> activityList=new List<Activity__c>();
     activityList=[SELECT ExternalAID__c,ID from Activity__c];                 
     Map<Integer,ID> activityMap = new Map<Integer,ID>();
     for(Activity__c activity_no:activityList){
     activityMap.put(Integer.valueOf(activity_no.ExternalAID__c),activity_no.ID);//map will always have unique values 
     }

      List<Payment__c> paymentList=new List<Payment__c>();
     paymentList=[SELECT External_Pay__c,ID from Payment__c];                 
     Map<Integer,ID> paymentMap = new Map<Integer,ID>();
     for(Payment__c payment_no:paymentList){
     activityMap.put(Integer.valueOf(payment_no.External_Pay__c),payment_no.ID);//map will always have unique values 
     }

       List<Contact> contactList=new List<Contact>();
     contactList=[SELECT ExternalCID__c,ID from Contact];                 
     Map<Integer,ID> contactMap = new Map<Integer,ID>();
     for(Contact contact_no:contactList){
     contactMap.put(Integer.valueOf(contact_no.ExternalCID__c),contact_no.ID);//map will always have unique values 
     }


    for (Ticket__c ticket : req.tickets) {
      List<Activity__c> activity;
      List<Contact> contact;
      List<Payment__c> payment;

    Integer activity_ID=Integer.valueOf(ticket.Activity__c);
    ticket.Activity__c=activityMap.get(activity_ID);

    String payment_ID=ticket.Payment__c;
    if(!(String.isEmpty(payment_ID))) 
    { ticket.Payment__c=paymentMap.get(Integer.valueOf(payment_ID));
     }
    else{ticket.Payment__c=null;}

    Integer contact_ID=Integer.valueOf(ticket.Contact__c);
    ticket.Contact__c=contactMap.get(Integer.valueOf(contact_ID));


     }   
        insert req.tickets; 
        return req.tickets;
    }

}
```

Comment: btw. you have a bug in your code - `paymentMap` is never used, `activityMap` used instead :(

Comment: Relevant Idea: [ReadOnly annotation support for Apex Rest services](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kourAAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing queries that look at every row of the `Activity__c`, `Payment__c` and `Contact` objects.

A pattern that avoids the querying of so much data is to collect the relevant values values from the `req.tickets` collection first in sets and then only query for those relevant values e.g.:

```
Set<Integer> aids = new Set<Integer>();
for (Ticket__c ticket : req.tickets) {
    aids.add(Integer.valueOf(ticket.Activity__c));
}

activityList=[SELECT ExternalAID__c,ID from Activity__c WHERE ExternalAID__c IN :aids];
```